# Read the whole process memory into a buffer in C++

Tags: c++, windows, memory

i want to suspend and read a processes whole memory into a byte buffer. How can i do that? Also how to calculate the memory size? Im thinking to use ReadProcessMemory

Thanks

Comment: If you have a particular operating system in mind, it's probably worth adding that to the question. This is going to be very platform-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual memory is not often contiguous. (That's actually the point.) Thus, it doesn't really make sense, and may be indeed impossible, to copy a process' entire virtual memory space into a single contiguous buffer. There will be gaps in virtual memory that will have to be filled with some value in the buffer. These gaps could be large, and the buffer could be huge.

Tools that do this sort of thing (e.g. for forensic purposes) often save off *ranges* of memory, with metadata indicating the source virtual memory addresses for later re-assembly.

### Windows

You can first use [`VirtualQueryEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualqueryex) to discover the virtual memory ranges of the target process.

See this question: [Enumerate the pages in a memory range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15018376/119527)

Then use [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) to copy data from the remote process' virtual memory into a buffer in your local process.

Of course, none of these actions are atomic. If the target process is running, the virtual memory space could change while you are working.

There are "tool help" APIs available as well: [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ToolHelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for [`MiniDumpWriteDump`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump) and associated functions. Don't invent the wheel yourself.

Comment: is there any way to get the dump files content without writing onto the disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution easily on the google, like I found a few months ago. But in short you can achieve this with EnumProcesses, GetProcessMemoryInfo nad GetProcessImageFileName functions.

the list of process identifiers you can get like this:

```
DWORD adwProcesses[1024], dwNeeded, dwProcesses;
if (!EnumProcesses(adwProcesses, sizeof(adwProcesses), &dwNeeded)) { return 1; }
```

where you get all process identifiers. So you need know the exact number, how many processes were returned

```
dwProcesses = dwNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
```

print or save the memory usage for as many times as many processes you have

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, adwProcesses[k]);
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
//Get process memory info and path to process
GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc));
GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, szProcessName, sizeof(szProcessName) / sizeof(TCHAR));
```

so you get data
for process path:

```
strProcessName.Format(_T("PATH: %s"), szProcessName);
```

page file memory usage:

```
strProcessPFMemory.Format(_T("%u K"), (pmc.PagefileUsage / 1024));
```

peak page file memory usage:

```
strProcessPPFMemory.Format(_T("%u K"), (pmc.PeakPagefileUsage / 1024));
```

and so on.